# igztop, issue with unsufficient permissions in webshell

Tags: command-line, mlrun, igztop

I cannot run command `igztop` in MLRun WebShell. I got this mistake:

```
xiong @ iguazio-system 13:26:39 ] ~ $ igztop
No resources found.
Does the Service Account running this service have sufficient permissions? Use 'igztop --check-permissions' to find out.
xiong @ iguazio-system 13:26:44 ] ~ $ igztop --check-permissions
List pods: no
Delete pods: no
xiong @ iguazio-system 13:27:06 ] ~ $
```

I used maximal privileges in admin part `Identity/Account/Policies` but it was without success.

I probably need to setup different permissions. Did you solve the similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup addition privileges in level of `Iguazio platform/Services/You-WebShell service`, where you can see:

- `Environment Variables/Service accounts` and you can choose relevant value for your case e.g. Log Reader, Application Admin or Service Admin
- see UI with options

[image]